# How to update MST after deleting an edge from the graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph, minimum-spanning-tree, edges

I have a graph represented with adjacency lists and his MST represented by parent array.

My problem is that I need to delete an edge from the graph and update parent array.

I've already manage to do the cases when:

1. the edge doesn't exist;
2. the edge is in graph but not in MST (MST doesn't change);
3. and the edge is the only path from two nodes(in this case I return null, because the 
   graph is not connected).

What can I do when the edge is in MST and the edge in graph is in a cycle? I need to do this in **O(n+m) complexity**.

I write the costs of edges with red color.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just search the minimum-distance path of 
the now-disconnected tree portion 
to the rest of the tree and 
add that path in between-- which is a single edge.

Say your original tree is T. With the removal 
of the edge, it is now split into trees T1 and T2.

Take one of these-- say T2. 
Every  edge incident to a node on T2 is either 
on T2 or is one connecting T2 to T1. Among these 
edges incident to a node on T2, pick the one which 
( (has its other end at a T1 node) and 
(has the minimum cost among all such edges) ).
Search for this edge, say e=(u,v), takes O(|E|) time. O(|N|) if the separated portion is a leaf.

if there were a tree, say T', with less cost than T1 \union T2 \union {e}, 
then the node sets N1 and N2 of T1 and T2 would have more inter-connections than just one edge,

i.e., there would be two or more more edges on T' that begin at a node in N1 and end at a node in N2. 
Otherwise, ( (T1 and T2 are minimum spanning trees resply. over  N1 and N2) and (e is the least costly 
connection between T1 and T2) ) would be false. But then, any go-between T1 and T2 is costlier than e=(u,v)-- contradicts.

Skipped some proof details. hope this helps.

Comment: thank you. It really helped me to know that those 2 trees must be reconnected by just one edge and the MST will be maintained. First I search through MST to find T1 and T2 (it can be made in O(n) ) and after that I look for the edge that connects T1 and T2 and took the edge with the lowest cost - O(n+m).

Comment: ashley, the algorithm that you describe is O(n^3).

"Take one of these-- say T2". That's O(n) to find T1 and T2.

"Every edge incident to a node on T2 is either on T2 or is one connecting T2 to T1."

The number of edges connecting T1 to T2 is O(n^2) in the worst case. To determine if it connects T1 to T2 is O(n) (searching two lists to match one of set T1 and one of set T2). So that is O(n^3) to get the list of edges connecting T1 to T2.

Comment: I think this is `O(E)`. When finding the original MST, mark edges as in the MST with a property: `e.mst = 1` or `0`. After deleting an MST edge, search outward along the MST from each vertex, marking each vertex as part of the 'left' or 'right' halves of the split MST. This takes `O(E)` each side. Then for all edges `(u, v)` if `u` and `v` are in different MST halves, keep the smallest such edge and add it to the MST.