# How to correct MST after deleting an edge from the graph in O(|E|)?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, minimum-spanning-tree

I am studying algorithms, and I have seen an exercise saying the following:

> Let G=(V,E) be a weighted undirected graph. Let T be a MST for G. Let
>   e be an  edge in T and let G'=(V,E') be the graph which obtained from
>   G after deleting e (i.e. E'=E/{e} ). G' is a connected graph. Describe
>   an algorithm that corrects T such that we will get a MST T' for G' in
>   O(|E|).

A I understand that, with the removal of the edge, T is now split into two connected components T1 and T2 and we need to find the minimum-distance path to connect them which is a single edge, i.e. we need to find the minimal-weight edge that connects between T1 and T2.

The problem is that I don't know how to prove this algorithm and how to implement it in O(|E|). I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659191/how-to-update-mst-after-deleting-an-edge-from-the-graph) but it takes more than O(|E|).

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: The solution you referenced seems to take O(|E|), isn't it so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Note that |E| >= |V|.*

Choose any vertex, mark it as `component1`, iterate each connected vertex (along MST edges) and mark `component1` as well.  That's `O(|V|)`.

Find a vertex from the other component by scanning until not marked.  That's `O(|V|)` again.

Iterate each vertex in 2nd component (along MST edges), selecting non-MST edges that connect to `component1`.  Track minimum edge answer.  That's `O(|E|)`

Complexity O(|E|)

Comment: like it! how do I prove the correctness of this algorithm?

Comment: Well, the first component is proven one component because it was discovered via iteration.  Second component is proved because original MST minus an edge is exactly two components.  Finally, smallest edge connecting both by definition creates MST (that's how they're always generated)